# Кэшированные изображения sorl-thumbnail

Tags: django

В общем такая незадача, почистил вручную кэш картинок sorl-thumbnail'а (по умолчанию был media/cache), а они заново не создаются! Отсюда вопрос: как заново заполнить кэш? Как "сказать" sorl-thumbnail'у, что бы он закэшировал все заново? Вопрос конечно задал коряво, но не знаю как написать по-другому :)

Comment: Вообще по логике кэш должен создаваться автоматически... Почему это не работает - ума не приложу :(

Comment: В общем какая-то проблема с библиотеками, настраивал проект на чистой системе - и картинки не генерируются вообще.

Comment: А что в директиве THUMBNAIL_BASEDIR записано?
Советую проверить права доступа на директорию с кэшем.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В общем решил вот как: включил в thumbnail отладку

```
THUMBNAIL_DEBUG = True
```

и далее по хлебным крошкам из ошибок увидел,что thumbnail ломился в несуществующую папку

```
/media/cache
```

, да и притом с полным доступом(это уже настройки моего локального сервера, я не заморачивался настройкой пользователей). В общем, создал папку, дал ей права - и все заработало :) Отладку можно обратно менять на 'False'.

Comment: @ХэшКод Примите мой ответ на вопрос.